# URL Rewriting with port number and root folder in PHP

Tags: php, linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

I have written URL rewrite like this

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^home index.php

RewriteRule ^process login_do.php
RewriteRule ^logout logout.php
RewriteRule ^request event-request.php
RewriteRule ^gallery event-gallery.php
RewriteRule ^press-releases/([0-9]+)$ press_releases.php?y=$1
RewriteRule ^single_pr/([0-9]+)$ single_pr.php?id=$1
```

and it is working perfectly on IIS server after converting this into webconfig 
but when I deployed my application on XAMPP Linux it is not working and  showing,
REDIRECT loop on browser.

Can anyone guide me how to add port number and folder name in the URL rewrite, because I think IIS is considering localhost/myapplicaiton as localhost/index.php so that is why it is working in IIS.
Guide me for Linux and Windows.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Give us example of URL before and after rewriting.

Comment: i am not trying to achieve anything, i have already achieved, i am just asking why above code is not working for apache linux and windows.

Comment: But we don't know what the code is supposed to be doing... Give us example of expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, issue was related to mod_rewrite function was disabled in apache in linux operating system.
To find out mod_rewrite is enabled or disabled.
just run `php_info()` and search for `mod_rewrite`. this is an easy technique, there are multiple ways to find out mod_rewrite.
To enable `mod_rewrite`, go to your linux terminal and type this command `a2enmod rewrite` and restart apache `php_info()`.